# In a Canvas Variable text, color doesn't changes, it remains black

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, rgb

It seems that I'm doing something wrong due to which the *color* isn't getting affected in canvas, it remains black only, below is my code :

```
var l="Lorem Ipsum"  
l=l.replace(/%20/g," ");    
var index=l;
if(index==-1);

/*var elem = document.getElementById("wordCanv");
elem.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"; */      

var pixels=new Array();
var canv=$('canv'); 
var ctx=canv.getContext('2d');  

ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
ctx.fill();
var wordCanv=$('wordCanv');
var wordCtx=wordCanv.getContext('2d');
wordCtx.fillStyle="blue";
wordCtx.strokeStyle="blue";
wordCtx.fill();
var mx=-1;
var my=-1;
var words="";
var txt=new Array();
var cw=0;
var ch=0;
var resolution=1;
var n=0;
var timerRunning=false;
var resHalfFloor=0;
var resHalfCeil=0;
```

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not selecting any element. `$('canv')` will look for elements with the tag `canv` (no element). You have to add a `#` to the selector to select by ID like: `$('#canv')`.

Second, `$(selector)` return an array-like object of the selected elements (if any), so you have to specify the index of which element to select like: `var canv = $('#canv')[0];`.

Third, `fill` fills the whatever shape that has just been drawn. If you want to fill the entire canvas use this instead: `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);`.

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
// select the canvas properly
var canv = $('#canv')[0];
// get it context
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');  

// set the style
ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.strokeStyle="blue";

// fill the rect
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='canv'></canvas>
```